# Pandas Series of hour values to Series of dates

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a time series covering January of 1979 with 6 hours time deltas. Time format is in continuous hour range:

```
1
7
13
18
25
31
.
.
.
739
```

Is it possible to convert these *ints* to dates? For instance:

```
1979/01/01 - 1:00
1979/01/01 - 7:00  
1979/01/01 - 13:00
1979/01/01 - 18:00
1979/01/02 - 1:00
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: How do we infer the year? Is it just a constant?

Comment: Yes, it's constant

Answer (score 4):

***Setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'hour': [1,7,13,18,25,31]})
```

Use **`pd.to_datetime`** with the **`unit`** flag, and set the **`origin`** flag to the beginning of your desired year.

```
pd.to_datetime(df.hour, unit='h', origin='1979-01-01')

0   1979-01-01 01:00:00
1   1979-01-01 07:00:00
2   1979-01-01 13:00:00
3   1979-01-01 18:00:00
4   1979-01-02 01:00:00
5   1979-01-02 07:00:00
Name: hour, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: The answer did not appear to me. Using the params of to_datetime is clean! +1

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([1,7,13])    
s = pd.to_datetime(s*1e9*60*60+ pd.Timestamp(1979,1,1).value)
print(s)
```

Returns:

```
0   1979-01-01 01:00:00
1   1979-01-01 07:00:00
2   1979-01-01 13:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Could also just do this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

s = pd.Series([1,7,13,18,25])
s = s.apply(lambda h: datetime(1979, 1, 1) + timedelta(hours=h))
print(s)
```

Returns:

```
0   1979-01-01 01:00:00
1   1979-01-01 07:00:00
2   1979-01-01 13:00:00
3   1979-01-01 18:00:00
4   1979-01-02 01:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```